# HTML generated by Jupyter Book does not recognise inline equations

Tags: markdown, jupyterbook

The official JupyterBook documentation states that simply placing an equation between two $ signs should be all that is needed, e.g. `$y = wx + b$`. Unfortunately, on creating the book (`jb build ...` on the command line) the HTML file is generated incorrectly so that the equation is not recognised and, therefore, rendered as plain text (including the $ signs).

Interestingly, blocked equations using double $$ signs come out correctly.

Updating JupyterLab to 4.0.3 had no effect, same with updating the following:

- Jupyter Book      : 0.15.1
- External ToC      : 0.3.1
- MyST-Parser       : 0.18.1
- MyST-NB           : 0.17.2
- Sphinx Book Theme : 1.0.1
- Jupyter-Cache     : 0.6.1
- NbClient          : 0.5.13

An extensive search yielded no answers.

At least it was possible to find out that HTML generated via the export function of JupyterLab works flawlessly.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found that "dollarmath" was disabled as default, so in your _config.yml file, simply enable it and it works (at least it did for me)

For example:

```
parse:
  myst_enable_extensions:
    # don't forget to list any other extensions you want enabled,
    # including those that are enabled by default!
    - amsmath
    - dollarmath
```